# To convert object node to json node

Tags: apache-flink

Here DataStream returns keyvalue pair as a object i need key value directly not as a object becoz i need to group the values based on key.

```
DataStream<ObjectNode> stream = env
    .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>("test5", new JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema (false), properties));

// stream.keyBy("record1").print();
```

when i give stream.keyby("record1").print(); 
it shows

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: This type (GenericType<org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode>) cannot be used as key.
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.operators.Keys$ExpressionKeys.<init>(Keys.java:330)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.keyBy(DataStream.java:337)
    at ReadFromKafka.main(ReadFromKafka.java:27)
```

Answer (score 1):

David Anderson's response is correct, as an addition, I can add that You can simply create the `KeySelector` that will extract the key as `String`. It could look like this:

```
public class JsonKeySelector implements KeySelector<ObjectNode, String> {
    @Override
    public String getKey(ObjectNode jsonNodes) throws Exception {
        return jsonNodes.get("key").asText();
    }
}
```

This obviously assumes that the Key is supposed to be `String`.

Comment: Thanks for adding this clarification!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to specify the key selector in a Flink keyBy. For example, if you have a POJO of type Event with the String key in a field named "id", any of these will work:

```
stream.keyBy("id")
```

```
stream.keyBy(event -> event.id)
```

```
stream.keyBy(
    new KeySelector<Event, String>() {
        @Override
        public String getKey(Event event) throws Exception {
            return event.id;
        }
    }
)
```

So long as you can compute the key from the object in a deterministic way, you can make this work.

Comment: my kafka producer code is this ``` KafkaProducer<String, integer> record = new KafkaProducer<>("topic",
            "recordtypes",index);``` record type means say record1,record2,record3. in flink i need group based on records(say record1,record2,record3).